# how do i create a profile page that shows all users post to the user and to other users

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

am new to Django and am trying to create a blog site where users can sign up and post articles, but my problem is how can I display a user's post on the user's profile page so that when other users reading the post clicks on the author's name it takes them to the `post.author's` profile page with the `post.author's` recent post listed and not the `request.user's` post. here is my code.

here is accounts/views.py

```
views.py

@login_required()
def user_profile_view(request, username):
    post = User.objects.filter(courses__author=username)
    context = {'courses': courses}
    return render(request, 'accounts/user_profile_view.html', context)
```

and here is post/models.py

```
models.py

class Posts(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cover = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='post_featured_image',
                                processors=[ResizeToFill(600, 300)],
                                format='png',
                                options={'quality': 80},
                                blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

here is the template

```
post_list.html


{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-lg-6">
    {% for course in courses_list %}
    <div class="central-meta item">
        <div class="user-post">
            <div class="friend-info">
                {% if post.author.profile.avatar %}
                <figure>
                    <img src="{{ post.author.profile.avatar.url }}" alt="">
                </figure>
                {% else %}
                <img src="{% static 'default.ico' %}" alt="">
                {% endif %}
                <div class="friend-name">
                    <ins><a href="{% url 'accounts:user_profile' post.author.username %}" title="">{{ course.author.get_full_name|title }}</a></ins>
                    <span>published: {{ post.published }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="post-meta">
                    {% if course.cover %}
                    <img src="{{ post.cover.url }}" alt="">
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="friend-name">
                        <ins><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" title="">{{ course.title|title }}</a></ins>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p><span>{{ post.summary|capfirst }}</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

here is my accounts/urls.py

```
urls.py

app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/profile/<str:username>/', user_profile_view, name='user_profile'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able do that, easy and via lots of ways.

make  a post model like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = foreign_key(User, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = char_field()
    content ........
```

so with that related name you will be able to reverse from user to its posts too!.
in your template do this:

```
<a href={{ post.author.get_absolute_url }} target="_blank">{{ post.author }}</a>
```

this link will redirect user to the posts author dashboard if you arrange the urls pattern correctly.

then for sorting authors posts, you have to pass the dashboard_owner to the template and use this name instead of user which normally will refer to the request.user -> user who are visiting the page

```
{% for post in dash_owner.posts.all %}
    <li> <a href="{{ post.get_abslute_url }}" target="_blink"> 
         {{ post.title }} </a> </li>
{% endfor %}
```

in views.py

```
def dashboard(request, owner_id=None)
    if owner_id:
        dash_owner = get_or_404(User, id=owner_id)
    elif request.user.is_authenticated:
       dash_owner = User.objectd.get(id=request.user.id)
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'dash_owner': dash_owner})
```

in urls.py -> urlpatterns:

```
path('dashboard/<int:owner_id>/', views.dashboard, name="dashboard")
```

this is the idea behind that, but for get the better result, you may need to clearly define the get_absolute_url of User model, to give you the url which machts to

```
'dashboard/<int:id/'
```

or another way is instead of that, do this:

```
<a href="{% url 'dashboard' post.author.id %}"> {{ post.author }} </a>
```

Comment: how do i query the posts from the database in the views am kindah stuck there

Comment: hi I edited the answer, and also I should tell if you restrict the view by login_required decorator, then not everyone will be able to visit other users dashboard!

Comment: pls can i forward the files to you so you can preview it and know whats the best practice for it?

Comment: unfortunately I am new to django and so I'm not familiar with its best practices